# Does the series for $\cos(x)/x$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence of
$$
a_x  ={\cos (x)\over x}
$$
does converge to zero.
As a result, intuitively
$$
\sum_{x=1}^\infty {\cos (x)\over x}
$$
should also converge right? But I've been told that the series diverges. This shouldn't be true... right?

Comment: What is $n$ in your definition of $a_n$ ?
Do you mean $cos(n)/n$?

Comment: Are you sure you formatted the question right? It isn't making much sense to me at the moment.

Comment: sorry, i'll edit it

Comment: When $n=0,$ the term $\cos(0)/0$ is not defined. Do you mean to sum from $n=1$ to $\infty$?

Comment: If a series converges, then the limit of the general term must be $0$. The converse is not true, as the usual example of the harmonic series shows.

Answer (score 2):

It is not at all intuitive to me that the series ought to converge simply because the terms go to zero. For example $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1n$ is well known to diverge even though $\frac1n\to 0$. Or, as an even easier example, consider
$$ 1 + \underbrace{\frac12+ \frac12}_{2\text{ halves}} +
\underbrace{\frac13 + \frac13+ \frac13}_{3\text{ thirds}} +
\underbrace{\frac14 + \frac14 + \frac14+  \frac14}_{4\text{ fourths}}+
\underbrace{\frac15 + \frac15+  \frac15+ \frac15+\frac15}_{5\text{ fifths}}+
\cdots $$

---

It does look like your particular series converges (conditionally), by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), though.